# Can I prove " For each real numbers can be expressed as sum of two irrational numbers." like this?

Tags: solution-verification

Can I prove it like this?

***Proof***

**Case 1**  Suppose $x=\sqrt2$  . Choose $y=\sqrt2-\sqrt3$ , $z=\sqrt3$

consider $y+z=(\sqrt2-\sqrt3)+\sqrt3=\sqrt2=x$

**Case 2** Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}$-{$\sqrt2$}. Choose $y=x-\sqrt2$, $z=\sqrt2$

consider $y+z=(x-\sqrt2)+\sqrt2=x$

Therefore ,For each real numbers can be expressed as sum of two irrational numbers.

Comment: Can you prove $x - \sqrt{2}$ is irrational in Case 2? For instance, what if $x = \sqrt{2} + 2$?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider different cases of whether $x$ is rational or irrational.

Comment: My initial reaction was that this might require some cleverness to show when $x$ is irrational (when $x$ is rational it's easy, at least to me), so I gave it some thought just now, and I was embarrassed to find it's even easier when $x$ is irrational (if $x$ is irrational, then $x/2$ is irrational). Slightly harder, but still not very difficult, is to show that you can use *different* irrationals in forming the sum.

Comment: If $x$ is irrational you could use $x/3$ and $2x/3$ as well (or $\epsilon x$ and $\delta x$ for any nonzero rational $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ that sum to $1$).

Comment: If $x$ is rational, by choosing any irrational $r$, both $\,\frac12(x+r)\,$ and $\,\frac12(x-r)\,$ are irrational, and we have $x=\frac12(x+r)+\frac12(x-r)$.

Comment: Or also $x= (x+r)+(-r)$, etc.